# Eclipse: Building both C++ and C files

Tags: eclipse, clang, llvm

Eclipse: Juno on Ubuntu 13.04

I'm trying to build a Clang project under Eclipse.  I got and installed the llvm4eclipsecdt add-in and it works, I guess (it does compile to object files).

My problem is that I have a mixture of C++ and C source files (.cpp and .c extensions), and when I create a new C++ project, all the cpp files are included, but not the C files.  And vice versa if I create a C project.

I'm thinking what I actually want is a C++ project and tell the C++ compiler to build the C files.

However, I have a lot of C files in my project, and I don't want to manipulate each one by one to tweak their build options or whatever.

Is there anything I can do project-wide to say "Yeah, I know this is a C++ project.  Go ahead and compile the .c files too?"

Thanks!